# Kubernetes with Apache and SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, kubernetes

I'm setting up this new deployment and trying to understand how SSL will work.
I see that I can deploy an SSL service to my container, but I can also configure my Apache to have SSL directly. So I'm trying to understand the different approaches and the best way.

I'm using a provided external load balancer.
Do I set up SSL service to that and then have it connect to the back end via port 80 or 443 and SSL as well? or can I make the load balancer port 443 and then just implement the SSL on Apache directly?

Answer (score 0):

The way to manage the scenario is doing SSL offloading at Load balancer level.

So you traffic will move like

```
internet > ingress > ingress-controller as background > service > deployment > pod > container
```

You can not implement the apache with each service, if you are running 15-20 or more services managing apache along with the application service container will be hard.

So you have to use the ingress controller which will manage the routing rules in the cluster and you can attach the certificate SSL/TLS to ingress.

> Ingress rule managed by the ingress controller.

Your SSL/TLS certificate will get stored into the Kubernets secret and that will attach to ingress.

Instead of using the apache, i would recommend trying the Nginx ingress.

Read this blog for SSL/TLS & Nginx ingress setup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes